# Kubernetes not found on skaffold dev command

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, skaffold, snap

I get this error when running skaffold dev command:

- stdout: ""
- stderr: "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?\n"
- cause: exit status 1  subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
  unable to connect to Kubernetes: getting client config for Kubernetes client: error creating REST client config in-cluster: unable to load in-cluster configuration, KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST and KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT must be defined

Should i set up the env variables?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing something like this, try adding:

`owner @{HOME}/.minikube/certs/*` to `/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.docker.docker`

and then run

```
apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.docker.docker
```